# React Native Expo: Saving Image after applying filters to it with react-native-gl-image-filters

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using the react-native-gl-image-filters library to applying some filters to my

```
  state = {
...settings,
hue: 0.0,
blur: 0.0,
sepia: 0,
sharpen: 0.0,
negative: 0,
contrast: 1,
saturation: 1,
brightness: 0.5,
temperature: 400,
```

};

render() {
let photo = this.props.navigation.getParam("photo", "empty");

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Surface
      style={{ width, height: width }}
      ref={(ref) => (this.image = ref)}
    >
      <ImageFilters {...this.state} width={width} height={width}>
        {{ photo }}
      </ImageFilters>
    </Surface>
```

How can I save the image after applying the filters on it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in the example
https://snack.expo.io/@gregoryrn/expo-gregorynative-react-native-gl-image-filters

code is

```
saveImage = async () => {
if (!this.image) return;

const result = await this.image.glView.capture();
console.warn(result);};
```